# Return the Next Item in a ListView with a twist

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, naudio

I've been working on the past couple of days on a ListView based Music player using NAudio in C#. It's now time for me to start working on the forward/previous functions but I've come to a bit of a bump in the road. I need to select whatever the next item in the listView I have is. However, it is not selected by the user but instead is marked as now playing by a checkmark next to it with the default ListView checkboxes.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I've got a public string that's accessible by anything; it has the filename of the currently playing track in it. Whenever I click to play a track, I've got a foreach loop that loops through all of the items in this listView (I've got a second listview in another tab that has all the music I click to play from) and if the filename subitem and currentlyPlaying string match, then it checks it. If not, it unchecks.

I've got an event handler in my mainclass for when the playback stops on the track. What's going to go in there will be the logic for the next track. I've got a general idea of what to do but I'm not sure how to go about doing it

1. Get the index of the item with the check mark next to it
2. Get the item after it
3. Retrieve its fileName subitem
4. Play it

So what would be the way to go about doing this? I'm still a bit confused with listViews and such.

**Update:** Also, how possible is it to disable the user checking the check box, I've got it down for when it's a double click but what about when the user checks the checkbox themselves?

**Update 2:** Here's the eventhandler with some scratch code I was working on

```
public void waveOutDevice_PlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName;
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in playListView.Items)
    {
        fileName = lvi.SubItems[1].Text;
        if(lvi.Checked == true)
        {
            int finIndex;
            lvi.Checked = false;
            finIndex = lvi.Index;
            //finIndex + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your eventhandler?  it is tough to say without some code.  Sidenote - you can disable the user from checking the checkbox by using the readonly property.

Comment: right now, the eventhandler has just some scratch code I was experimenting with. im editing the post right now with it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just about there.  all you need to do is something like this:

```
public void waveOutDevice_PlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName;
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in playListView.Items)
    {
        fileName = lvi.SubItems[1].Text;
        if(lvi.Checked == true)
        {
            int finIndex;
            lvi.Checked = false;
            finIndex = lvi.Index;
            finIndex++;
            if(finIndex < playListView.Count())
            {
                var nextGuy = playListView.Items[finIndex];
                nextGuy.Checked = true;
                //Play the file and what not. 
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it would work, however it doesn't but fear not, I'm pretty sure it's an NAudio issue. I'll play around with it some more. Also, in the second if, did you mean playListView.Items.Count?